# How to display Navigation Pane (Ms Word feature) in LibreOffice Writer?

Tags: microsoft-word, libreoffice

I'm new to LibreOffice and wondering if it possible to view Navigation Pane (Heading and Subheadings) on the left pane like in Ms Word?

I know the same question has been asked here, but they didn't really answer it.
https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/150432/how-do-i-view-the-heading-and-subheadings-on-the-left-pane-like-in-mswords/

Here is the screenshot of the left pane on Ms Word taken from https://www.howtogeek.com/58924/use-the-navigation-pane-in-word-to-easily-reorganize-documents/. Look at the Navigation pane on the left. That's what I wanted on LibreOffice.
[image]

There is Navigator feature (View > Navigator (F5)) in LibreOffice Writer, but you'll notice that it's not the same as Navigation Pane in Ms Word.

I'm looking for something similar, so that it would be easier for me to browse the content of the document.

If this feature is not available in LibreOffice, please let me know the alternative.

Also, if this is not the right channel to ask about LibreOffice, please let me know and I'll delete this post move it to the right place.

Comment: @Biswapriyo, if you ever use Ms Word, you know that's not the same at all. Refer to the screenshot above.

Answer (score 1):

1) Display the Navigator (`View -> Navigator`)

2) In the resulting window, you should see the following:

[image]

The first row of icons allows for navigation (explore the options)

Clicking on the last icon in the second row will give you a drop down menu allowing you to choose outline levels displayed.